# How to disable the RAID in x3400 M2

Tags: centos, raid, boot, ibm

Hi I just wanna disable the default RAID in my server IBM System X3400 M2 Server(7837-24X),i have 3 disk drives SAS.
I want to make them a JBOD "Just a Bunch Of Disks", because I want to install in the drive 0 CentOS, and the other two make them cache files for a squid server.
I disable the RAID in the BIOS:

```
System Settings/Adapters and UEFI drivers/LSI Logic Fusion MPT SAS Driver
-PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0X0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)
```

LSI Logic MPT Setup Utility

```
RAID Properties/Delete Array
```

Later I boot the CentOS live CD and install the OS in the drive 0, and the others 2 mounted like this:

```
*LVM Volume Groups
vg_proxyserver     139508
lv_root            51200    /    ext4
lv_home        84276    /home    ext4
lv_swap        4032
Hard Drive
sdb(/dev/sdb)
free        140011
sdc(/dev/sdc)
free        140011
sdd(/dev/sdd)
sdd1        500    /boot    ext4
sdd2        139512 vg_proxyserver    physical volume(LVM)
```

But when I restart the server give me the error:

```
Boot failed Hard Disk 0
UEFI PXE PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0X0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(001A64B15130,0X0))
........PXE-E18:Server response timeout.
UEFI PXE PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0X0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(001A64B15132,0X0))
........PXE-E18:Server response timeout.
```

and the OS not start. The IBM force me to do a RAID?,why?

Comment: Same question as http://superuser.com/questions/506594/disable-raid-to-jbod-in-server-ibm-x3400-m2

Comment: yes,it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Raid 10 or 5? I am assuming that you have a 4 drive chassis. It's easy to make separate partition for Squid file to reside. Just do a custom partition setup in the Cent installer. Performance will be better and you will eliminate a single point of failure setup using single drives.

Comment: Well I have only 3 disk drive SAS, and my raid controller not support RAID 5 (Model Hot-swap con PCI-Express ServeRAID-BR10i for RAID-0, -1 and 1-E)